# Facebook 3.0 : Session.newPermissionsRequest callback not get called

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, publish

I was using the openForRead to ask for the read permissions and after the callback I set for the openForRead I made another publish stream request using newPermissionsRequest and assigned it with a new callback to it. But the new callback didn't get called.

Does anyone know why is that? It does ask me the publish permission but when i clicked ok, the callback didn't get called.

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem, quite dangerous to release without proguard on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please update to the 3.0.1 release. This was a bug that got fixed.

See the [changelogs](https://developers.facebook.com/android/change-log-3.x/).

Comment: I have updated the Facebook SDK to 3.0.1 as you mentioned, still the problem persists with proguard, can you suggest something else.

Answer (score 1):

the callback should add new to the session,
like this

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest request = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, Arrays.asList(FACEBOOK_POST_PERMISSIONS));
session.removeCallback(oldCallback);
session.addCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {                        }
        });
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(request);
```